# Chain is reluctant to shift into hardest gear on rear cassette

Tags: gears

I have a Giant Escape, with Shimano Acera gears (3 speed on the front, 7 speeds on the back). When the chain is in the hardest gear on the front cassette, then it is reluctant to shift into the hardest gear on the back cassette, otherwise it works fine.

When shifting from 6th to 7th, it stays in 6th while making a rattling sound for anywhere from 1 second to a minute, before changing to 7th.

I've tried decreasing the gear chain tension until it is basically slack when in 6th, but this doesn't help. I also don't think it is the limit screws (it was working fine before) and it shifts fine when not in the hardest gear on the front.

Also, this started when I had the rear wheel replaced 1 month ago.

Edit:

This only seems to happen when I'm riding the bike, when it is stationary and I am pedalling by hand, everything works fine, for some reason. Also, I've tried replacing both the inner and outer gear cable.

Comment: How is the cable tension when you're trying to go to big-front and small-rear cog?  Is it so loose that its dangling with slack?

Comment: @Criggie It's dangling just a bit, there's very little tension

Comment: Try hanging the bike up and carefully use your finger to encourage the rear deraileur out to the little cog while slowly peddling.  Mind the fingers though.  This is to see if the deraileur is capable ot getting to the right place or not.  I wonder if its subtily bent ?

Comment: @Criggie See the edit, everything works fine if I am not actually on the bike

Comment: when you replaced the wheel, did you replace the cassette, or did you keep the old one and use it on the new one? It could also be a bent derailleur hanger which is common, and i believe for your bike, replaceable. images would be helpful.

Comment: The cassette is the same, and I'll upload pictures later

Comment: have you tried adjusting the limit screw? It'd not uncommon if you do something like changing a wheel, that distances can change slightly. Also frames can flex under load, which might explain why you don't see anything when the bike is in a stand

Comment: Did you torque the cassette to specification?

Comment: It sure sounds like the limit screws need tweaking.  The other slight possibility is that the axle/hub is flexing slightly under load, which may be what Frisbee is thinking.

Comment: Have you checked that the wheel is sitting fully in the dropout? Sometimes it only needs to be slightly lower on one side for it to disrupt the indexing of the gears.

Comment: @Frisbee A professional bike mechanic replaced my wheel, so I'm not sure (but I should hope he did). I also don't have a torque wrench at the moment, so I can't measure it.

Comment: @PeteH I will try adjusting the limit screws in the weekend, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was in fact the H limit screw.

Comment: Good work - thank you for the closure.  You can click the big tick/check on the left (below the up/down vote buttons) to confirm this is the accepted answer.